# Can't pass uniform values to shader in LWJGL

Tags: shader, lwjgl

Attempting to get some simple tutorial-level shaders working for LWJGL. I have a working setup that can simply color in a block when I specify all the colors in the shader itself, but now I am trying to pass a float value in to the shader to specify a simple grey scale.

Frag shader looks like this:

```
varying vec4 vertColor;
uniform float light;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(light, light, light, 1);
}
```

And the code right before rendering a block:

```
if(useShader)
{
    int loc = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(program, "light");
    System.out.println("LOC: " + loc);
    ARBShaderObjects.glUniform1fARB(loc, 1.0f);
    ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(program);
}
```

Frag shader originally specified `gl_FragColor = vertColor`, which works, and I can replace `light` in the `vec4` with any float value and it works. But as I have it, no matter what I pass to `ARBShaderObjects.glUniform1fARB`, the square will always be black when I render it; I'm assuming this is due to `uniform float light` being defaulted to `0.0f`, which sounds like my uniform variable is not being set.

If at all relevant, I do see LOC to be 0 when it is printed out.

Would like to know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the the order of these two lines from:

```
ARBShaderObjects.glUniform1fARB(loc, 1.0f);
ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(program);
```

To:

```
ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(program);
ARBShaderObjects.glUniform1fARB(loc, 1.0f);
```

You need to start using the program before you upload the uniform value.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that one already, but it worked. Thanks!